# jQuery checking if Ajax request response equals to specific value does nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, response

I'm using jQuery and Ajax to send my form data over to a PHP script and that all works well.
But when I'm trying to check the response value of the Ajax request to determine which SweetAlert text I need to show the user things start not functioning.
When checking if the response is equal to "success" a SweetAlert modal should pop up but nothing happens but in the browser console I can clearly see that the only response from the server is "success". However if any of the else if statements are true (meaning the server sent that response that it's looking for) then SweetAlert works just fine.
I have used this response checking system for months and it has worked perfectly but a day ago it just stopped working and I didn't update or change anything related to SweetAlert and jQuery.
My code:

```
$("#createIncidentBtn").click(function(e) { //Kui uue intsidendi loomis nuppu vajutatakse, siis
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#createIncidentBtn").val('Please wait...'); //Muudab uuendamis nupu teksti
    message = simplemde.value();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/status/main/php/dashboard-process.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $("#new_incident_form").serialize()+'&action=new_incident'+'&message='+simplemde.value(),
        success:function(response) {
            $("#createIncidentBtn").val('Create Incident'); //Muudab intsidendi loomis nupu teksti
            console.log(response); //The response from the server is "success" (without the quotes)
            if(response === 'success') { //This if statement does not work
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'New Incident successfully created!', //Näitab modali, mis ütleb, et informatsiooni uuendati edukalt
                    icon: 'success',
                    type: 'success'
                });
            } else if(response === 'No title or message') { //This else if statement works
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'You forgot to enter a title or message!', //Näitab modali, mis ütleb, et informatsiooni uuendati edukalt
                    icon: 'error',
                    type: 'error'
                });
            } else if(response === 'Invalid incident status') { //This else if statement also works
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'The incident status you have selected is invalid', //Näitab modali, mis ütleb, et informatsiooni uuendati edukalt
                    icon: 'error',
                    type: 'error'
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

What's weird is that when I change the first if statement to this: `if(response.includes('success')) {` then it works perfectly and a SweetAlert modal shows up.
But the thing is that my PHP script is not outputting anything else besides "success" as I can see in the browser console.
I also checked if any of my other pages are having this issue and they are all having the same issue all of a sudden and I have not changed anything on the other pages. But I have confirmed that SweetAlert works without the if statement.

Thanks for any help,
Nimetu.

Comment: my guess is it is not exactly what you think it is. `console.log(escape(response))`; Using a better format like JSON prevents issues like this.

Comment: What's console.log(escape(response)); meant to do? When I put it in my code I got this response: success%20

Comment: So you have a whitespace. I again highly recommend you have your backend return JSON so you do not have to worry about things like this.

Comment: Based on your console.log, change `if(response === 'success')` to `if(response === 'success ')` or (much better) change your response so that it returns `"success"` and not `"success "` note that  `" " !== ""` and you won't see trailing whitespace in the browser console.

Comment: *What's console.log(escape(response)); meant to do* - this converts whitespace that you otherwise can't see into escape characters - ie the trailing `" "` has become `%20`.   An alternative is something like `console.log("[" + response + "]")` which assumes response is a string and would output `[success ]` - hopefully the trailing space becomes more obvious in these cases compared with just `console.log(response)`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I looked into my code and for some reason all of my success echos suddenly have a trailing whitespace and I have not touched the other parts of the code in months. Why is it that I suddenly have trailing whitespaces at every success echo when I have not even edited those parts of the code?

Comment: I also removed the success echo from the script and without it the script is still outputting a %20 so I'm assuming it's coming from somewhere else not the success echo statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has now been resolved.
It was caused by a trailing whitespace.
I did not find out why the script randomly started outputting a random trailing whitespace even without any echo statement. It even did this in parts of the code that had not been edited in months.
But if you are using Visual Studio Code then this shortcut will delete all trailing whitespaces: **Ctrl K** + **Ctrl X**. Which resolved my issue.